# Copy fork repository to a local branch

Tags: git, github, copy, branch, git-fork

I have forked a project on Github and cloned it on my local machine. I created some new files and directories in the master branch. The problem is I want a new branch with only the files from the forked project not the files added in the branch master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a new remote which tracks the project you forked from, which is a good idea anyway if you plan to reintegrate your changes or keep the projects in sync, and then start the branch from their master.

```
git remote add upstream <original-project-url>
git fetch upstream
git branch <branchname> upstream/master
```

Otherwise you will have to manually find out which was the commit where your master branch diverged from the upstream (i.e. the point where you forked) and then start the branch from there:

```
git branch <branchname> <commit-id-of-the-fork>
```